# How to set cookie name dynamically in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I am trying to set cookie name dynamically in my rails application.

I am able to set cookie like this:

```
cookies[:users_id] = current_user.id
```

I want to set the cookie name dynamically. I tried like this and it's not working:

```
cookies[:'users_id_#{current_user.id}'] = current_user.id
```

How is it possible?

Comment: What do you want to achieve on higher level with this code, BTW?

Comment: Actually I don't want to set the cookie for user_ids. I just took an example for asking the question. The actual implementation is on an Article rating system, where an Article cannot be rated multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string as well as symbol, and if you want to perform interpolation, you need to use double ticks (`"`)

```
cookies["users_id_#{current_user.id}"] = current_user.id
```